# Foursquare page update with photo

Tags: api, foursquare

I have successfully implemented the new "pageupdates/add" API for a venue with just a shout (i.e. no photo or special). Now I would like to add support for setting a photo on a page update. I assume that the "photos/add" entry point should be called first to add a photo and then use the returned photo's ID in the pageupdate add call. My question is, how should the photo be added? In other words, should the photo be added to the venue (i.e. specify venueId)? Can the photo be marked private so it's only visible with the page update? I want to make sure I'm using the API as designed for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API endpoint/behavior for adding photos to a page update is not finalized and hasn't been released yet. Will let you know when it's available.

Comment: It's been a while. Any updates on this? And what about specifying a "special" with a pageupdate? Thx!

Comment: You can specify a pageId when adding a photo now, then reference the photoId when creating the update: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/photos/add